# Latex listings - breaklines divides parenthesis, wrong space near parenthesis

Tags: spacing, parentheses, listings

When using `listings` package, there is a wrong spacing after parenthesis and, when a line breaks, the parenthesis are very often divided from what comes before.
What can I do to change that? The output is really ugly. Below is an example of a problematic listing.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\lstset{
language={[5.2]Lua},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
breaklines=true
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a minimal page.

This is not correct \lstinline{function test(c) math.sqrt(c) + 22456*math.sqrt(c) end}.

This is correct \texttt{function test(c) math.sqrt(c) + 22456*math.sqrt(c) end}.

\begin{lstlisting}
if not something then
    local m = foo:doSomething(object.untriedthings)
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using another package.

I used the package `minted`, after installing the package `pygments`.
In the preamble I put the following code:

```latex
\setminted{breaklines} 
\newminted{lua}{frame=single}
```

Then, for every inline code I used the command `\mintinline{lua}{...}` and for other code `\begin{luacode} ... \end{luacode}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this option to your `\lstset`:

```
\lstset{
...
keepspaces = true
}
```

This outputs:

[image]

---

See more details at the doc of [`listings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section 5.11).

As the doc says:

> `keepspaces=true` tells the package not to drop spaces to fix column alignment and always converts tabulators to spaces.

The default value of `keepspaces` is `false`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It's a simple fix that doesn't involve switching to a different package entirely or abandoning syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one, perhaps sub-optimal, way of achieving a *better* line-break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\lstset{
  language={[5.2]Lua},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  breaklines=true,
  mathescape
}


\begin{document}

This is not correct \lstinline{function test(c) math.sqrt(c) + 22456*math.sqrt(c) end}.

\begin{sloppypar}
This is not correct \lstinline{function test(c) math.sqrt(c) + 22456*math.sqrt$\texttt{(c)}$ end}.
\end{sloppypar}

This is correct \texttt{function test(c) math.sqrt(c) + 22456*math.sqrt(c) end}.

\end{document}
```

A switch to regular `\texttt` (or boxing) keeps the text components together. In the example above, the text spills into the margin quite minimally. However, a `sloppypar` allows for the text to break at a somewhat better location.

I'd suggest leaving such fine-tuning for line-breaking until the end of your document setup, as they might resolve themselves naturally as your change the surrounding text.

Comment: I needed a more solid solution, but thank you anyway!